# How to change Legend text colors in recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'm trying to change text Legend colors in recharts

By default, legend takes colors based on lines/bars :

[image: exemple]

And I want :

[image: exemple2]

Seems like what I want was the previous default setting, because doc explain us how to have colorful legend texts : https://codesandbox.io/s/legend-formatter-rmzp9
https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Legend

I can't find how to do the reverse

Answer (score 6):

Ran into the same issue, solution is to the use the formatter:

```
<Legend
  formatter={(value, entry, index) => <span className="text-color-class">{value}</span>}
/>
```

The span returned from this function only renders in place of the text portion of the legend, the coloured shapes (circles in your example) aren't effected.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `stroke` prop of both `Line` components as follows. Codesandbox example given [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/legend-formatter-forked-m380k?file=/src/App.tsx:1159-1339).

`stroke="#FF0000"` refers to red color and `stroke="#000000"` refers to black color.

```
      <Line
        type="monotone"
        dataKey="pv"
        stroke="#FF0000"
        activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
      />
      <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#000000" />
```

Hope this would answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah if I change the lines colors,  the legend colors change accordingly. But what I want is changing only the legend text color. So if I have one line red and one line black, i still want to be able to change legend text color to blue for example